# HDMI not connecting (18.04 LTS) Intel

Tags: drivers, 18.04, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have just upgraded to 18.04, and all of a sudden my HDMI is not connecting.

`lshw -C video`

```
*-display 
VGA compatible controller
HD Graphics 530
Intel Corporation
ID: 2
version: 06
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

`xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93    48.00 
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   ...
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

`lspci | grep VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
```

Everything was working fine, before the upgrade.

What's my next step in troubleshooting this?

Comment: a) Asking others if they have/had a problem does not conform to our guidelines here, for it surely will pull "me, too" responses out of the woodwork. Instead, just ask what to do next. ... b) Try booting from a LiveUSB of your prior version, does the problem clear? If so, then a reinstall may be in order. Upgrades sometimes don't.